# Colocar valores de array en true javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Tengo un objeto, dentro de ese objeto, tengo dos propiedades. La primera propiedad es de tipo boolean; la segunda propiedad es de tipo boolean[].
Necesito colocar todos los valores del array de la segunda propiedad en true.
Supongo que podría hacer eso con un forEach, para que me recorra el array y vaya colocando true en cada array que recorra. Pero no se muy bien como lo podra hacer, por ahora, llevo esto...

```
selectCard(i) {
    this.cards[i].valueFlights.forEach(function(check, indexFlight) {

    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tú mismo diste la respuesta a tu pregunta, sólo te falta implementarlo de forma correcta. Digamos que tenemos un `Objeto` como describes, en el cual el arreglo de `boolean` tiene otros objetos (supongo)

```
$scope.item = { bool1: true, bool2: [ { val:... }, { val:... } ] }
```

La implementación correcta del [angular.forEach](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach) sería:

```
angular.forEach($scope.item.bool2, function(b){
   b.val = true;
})
```

Si no es lo que necesitas, me lo haces saber colega

Comment: No es lo que necesito exactamente. Ahí deje el código como lo tengo; si me podrías ayudar, por favor.

Comment: Donde le especificas la cantidad de valores que debe tener el array? Porque si solo declaras un array vacío podría ingresar valores infinitamente...

Comment: Si, ese el punto; no hay limites

Comment: Si no hay límites vas a llenar la memoria de la computadora y no podrás hacer nada más. Cual es tu objetivo con todo esto?

Answer (score 0):

Es muy bueno tu aporte; pero no es lo que necesito.
Lo tengo asi, no se si te puedes basar con esto

```
$scope.item = { bool1: boolean, bool2: boolean[] }[]
```

Necesito que lo que haya dentro de bool2 sea true, cada valor. Si tengo 20 indices de array, necesito que cada valor de esos array sean true.

Comment: estas usando las 'Respuestas' para hacer comentarios a otra respuesta.

Answer (score -1):

En la función hay un **for** que recorre todo el arreglo que le mandan y a cada valor se asigna como 'true' y se retorna el arreglo con todos los valores en 'true' al acabar.

```
const arregloConTodosLosBooleanosTrue = this.allTrue(bool2);

$scope.item = {
      bool1: boolean,
      bool2: arregloConTodosLosBooleanosTrue
    };

allTrue(value: boolean[]): boolean[] {
    for (const i of value) {
         i = true;
     }
     return value;
}
```

Comment: Intenta explicar que hace el código que has compartido para que tu respuesta sea bien recibida por la comunidad, revisate [cómo responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: En la propiedad de _bool2_ se usa una función donde se manda el valor que recibe.En la función hay un **for** que recorre todo el arreglo que le mandan y a cada valor se asigna como 'true' y se retorna el arreglo con todos los valores en 'true' al acabar.

Comment: Edita tu respuesta y añade la explicación allí